# Javascript - easelJS - how to removeAllListeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, easeljs, createjs

In the beginning of my code, I set a tick event. These 3 following lines work.

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
```

I would like to remove the listener at the end of my code. I tried to call it like that but it doesn't work:

```
createjs.Ticker.removeAllListeners();
```

The Firefox console says me `createjs.Ticker.removeAllListeners is not a function`.
So i tried to switch to the other one:

```
createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", handleTick);
```

And It also doesn't work.
I don't really know how to use it. On the official website they use it with a displayObject, but I don't create it link to a button or something else.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Ticker.html#method_removeAllEventListeners

Could someone could help me to solve it please ?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm using the easelJS version 0.7.1 but I think my problem is linked to a tutorial using an older version of easelJS (0.5). Does anyone know how to adapt it the the latest version of easelJS ? thanks

EDIT 2: I found on this link (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/modules/EaselJS.html) the utilization of `createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);` in the latest version of easelJS, but there is no documentation about how to remove the listener called from `createjs.Ticker`, i'm still looking for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is:

```
createjs.Ticker.removeAllEventListeners(); // Note the function name
```

The second example should work, assuming you are not proxying the function to maintain scope. Ticker is an EventDispatcher, and inherits all the methods defined here: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html

The `evt.remove()` is a great shortcut, if you don't have a reference to the function.

One important note: If you remove ALL event listeners from Ticker, you may inadvertedly stop Tween from working. Tween adds a listener when it is initialized. Your best option is the second option where you remove the listener entirely. If you still can't get it working, feel free to post some more code, and I will try and help out.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks it help to solve my problem and to better understand how it works.

Comment: Is evt of evt.remove() the parameter evt of the listener function added via addEventListener? If so, for me it doesn't stop the ticker listening. I also tried the on/off syntax which also fails to end the listening to 'tick'. Any hints?

Comment: evt.remove and evt.off need to be used with the `on()` method. This shortcut creates a wrapper for the event handler, which adds the additional functionality. To use `off()`, you need to store the wrapper created by `on()`, an use that instead of the actual function handler.

Answer (score 0):

I use the // alternately: evt.remove(); call.
Using a global var, when I set this one to true, I call the evt.remove() function. But It might not be the best way to do it.